# How to create temp table in node.js by use Sequelize and Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a question about: "How to create temp table in node.js by used Sequelize and Postgres"

I can not found anywhere how to do that without use query command, like findAll(), findOne() functions of the Sequelize

Answer (score 0):

sync({ force: true }) - This option force Sequelize to create a table, dropping it first if it already existed

```
const User = sequelize.define("User", {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
});

await User.sync({ force: true });
```

Comment: @nam-tran-thanh Was your question solved with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version of Sequelize (to date) which is 6.21.4, it doesn't support creating temp/temporary tables of Postgres by `sync()` method. [Source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6.21.4/src/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js#L118)

You could however create them using raw queries:

```
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(
  'CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (....)',
  { options }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization): you can do this by `sync({ force: true })`. Without the `force` option, it will create the table only if it doesn't exist.